# Can I multiple select object variables in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Something like doesn't work, what's the work around?

```
var tgtCol = $('td[aria-describedby=tblGrid_Subject]');
var tgtHdr = $('#tblGrid_Subject');
$(tgtHdr, tgtCol).attr('colSpan', '3');
```

Comment: Bennor has got the best answer.. I'll accept once I can (10 mins)

Comment: The point of putting them in a variable is because I'm using the targets more than once.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var tgtCol = $('td[aria-describedby=tblGrid_Subject]');
var tgtHdr = $('#tblGrid_Subject');
$(tgtHdr).add(tgtCol).attr('colSpan', '3');
```

This will also work:

```
var stuff = $('td[aria-describedby=tblGrid_Subject], #tblGrid_Subject');
stuff.attr('colSpan', '3');
```

Comment: +1 because it actually answers the question about selecting multiple OBJECTS.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you may combine multiple selectors with a comma, like so:

```
$('td[aria-describedby=tblGrid_Subject], #tblGrid_Subject').attr('colSpan', '3');
```

Comment: Not if you already have multiple objects and you don't know what events lead up to those objects being created.

Answer (score 1):

As the first two lines already return a jQuery object, you can just do it like this:

```
tgtHdr.attr('colSpan', '3');
tgtCol.attr('colSpan', '3');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) initially:

```
$('td[aria-describedby=tblGrid_Subject], #tblGrid_Subject').attr('colSpan', '3');
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's two selectors, you can use 'merge', but if it's more than two you should use 'each'

```
// using merge:
$.merge(selector1, selector2) // the rest

// using each:
$([selector1, selector2, selector3, .....etc]).each(function(){
    // your code here
});
```